# iOS devices not finding zebra printers via bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, zebra-printers

Hi I have a zebra QLn220 and 320 with bluetooth radios. They are both discoverable yet cannot be found on iOS devices that I have tested it with. However, my Mac Mini detects it and so does an Android device. I've tried resetting both the printers and the devices to no avail.

Comment: Only MFi printers work on apple devices. QLns do not have the MFi chip, the iMZs do though...  http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/printers/printer-type/mobile/mz-series.html

Comment: Thanks! good to know and iMZ is tested and working!